# how to set timeZoneId to the calendar in Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, timezone

I want to set time zone to a calendar object, how can I do that please

timeZoneId is of type ZoneId

I am converting date into hours and minutes but I want to set time zone id before getting the value.

how can get this to work please

```
fun getHoursAndMinutes(timeZoneId: ZoneId, date: java.util.Date): String {
    val cal = Calendar.getInstance()
    // Apply timezone if set
    cal.timeZone.id = timeZoneId
    cal.time = date
    val hours = cal.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY)
    val minutes = cal.get(Calendar.MINUTE)

    return "$hours : $minutes"
}
```

Thanks
R

Comment: Date and Calendar are legacy classes that have been replaced about 10 years ago by classes from java.time package. Can you use the newer classes instead?

Comment: @k314159 thank you for getting back, I can use newer classes. please suggest what I need to change please

Comment: Use `ZonedDateTime`. Then you have everything you need in the same class.